# Problem: My terminal settings are not saved

Tags: terminal, kali-linux

I am using kali linux 2020.4 over virtual box, and every time when I am trying to change the terminal settings, they are saved just to the current terminal, and when I open a new terminal it's like I haven't made any change.
What to do?

[image: termiinal settings]

Comment: Kali is not the easiest to use, and to get to work. There are many other Gnu/Linuxes that are easier.

Comment: you didn't give a solution... I want to solve this on my kali machine

Comment: Yes. Solutions are put in the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `QTerminal` :

Follow the steps indicated below:
Note: Either use the root user or use this with **sudo**

1. Goto ~/.config/qterminal.org folder
2. Change whatever setting you want to change and save then exit.
3. All set, remember don't use Qterminal to do the above steps, otherwise changes wont take place
4. Either use mate-terminal or do it with GUI editor.